# How to wget .mp4 files on Apache Directory

Tags: apache, wget

I want to download all .mp4 files from a "Index of" page using wget.
The target directory is http://ia600409.us.archive.org/27/items/MIT18.01JF07/

I've tried some commands (which I copied and pasted from websites), but they don't seem to work.
e.g.:

```
wget -r -l0 -nd --no-parent -A .mp4 -R ".*" 
    http://ia600409.us.archive.org/27/items/MIT18.01JF07/
```

Btw, I think the directory is *Apache*.

Answer (score 3):

```
wget -e robots=off -r -nd -np -A mp4 http://ia600409.us.archive.org/27/items/MIT18.01JF07
```